# Como remover a posição de um array com jquery

Tags: jquery, slice

Estou tentando retirar uma posição do array com slice, pelo que vi até só consigo tirar com a posição desse array, teria como eu tirar pelo value? Pois a posição do array muda muito em cada situação, estou tentando da seguinte forma:

```
if($j('#folog_manha').css('display') == "none"){
   var retornox = retorno.slice('Manhã');
}
```

Se caso não tiver como, como eu pegaria as posições desse array para comparar? no caso pegar a posição que se encontra 'Manhã' e dar um slice nela.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Para remover uma posição de um array pelo valor basta usares o [IndexOf](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_indexof.asp) no metodo [splice](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_splice.asp)

```
var arr = [ "abc", "def", "ghi" ];

arr.splice(arr.indexOf("def"), 1);
```

Comment: Funcionou como deveria, simples e pratico, obrigado.

Comment: de nada! fico grato por ter ajudado

Answer (score 3):

Tente fazer como neste exemplo:

```js
var arr        = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']; //Array inicial
var removeItem = 'c';   // Valor do array que será removido

arr = jQuery.grep(arr, function(value) {
    return value != removeItem;
});
console.log('Array após a remoção: ' + arr);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

No seu código ficaria assim:

```
if($j('#folog_manha').css('display') == "none"){
   var removeItem = 'Manhã';

   retorno= jQuery.grep(retorno, function(value) {
    return value != removeItem;
   });

   // new array
   // fica sem "manha"

}
```

O método `grep` do jQuery percorre todos os índices de um array e retorna aqueles que você deseja.

Referencia [link](https://gustavopaes.net/blog/2010/removendo-item-de-array-usando-jquery.html)

Comment: Eu coloquei na pergunta que gostaria de tirar pelo value dele, não pela posição pois ela muda dinamicamente dependendo da situação, Manhã pode ser 1, 2, 3, 4 etc..

Comment: mas jovem ele esta tirando pelo item. no caso ali se mudar para 4 ele tira o 4

Comment: Isso seria pela key dele, eu teria que saber a posição dele, então teria que fazer uma requisição a cada situação, pelo valor seria mais simples pois nunca muda. `(2) ["Comercial", "Manhã"]
0
:
"Comercial"
1
:
"Manhã"
length
:
2
__proto__
:
Array(0)`

Comment: Agora que vi que é uma outra função, pensei que fosse o slice, pois já tentei passando direto o valor e não funcionou, posso testar o seu, mas o do 13dev já funcionou pra mim

Comment: sim @GustavoSouza não tem problema. embora eu tenha respondido primeiro, e tenha feito em jquery que foi o que marcou na tag.

Comment: Sim, mas a dele foi mais pratica, com splice eu consigo remover direto do array original, assim podendo fazer varias verificações sem colocar em variáveis de apoio, pois terei que fazer umas 6 verificações dessa.